# Adicionar JComponents num JDialog/JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Então, eu tenho três `JLabel` e `JTextField` para adicionar em um painel, e dois `JButton` e um `JTable` para adicionar em outro painel, de modo que um fique em baixo do outro. Eu crio um painel mais genérico (`pnlPrincipal`) para setar suas posições através do `BorderLayout.`, adiciono tudo certinho, só que no `JDialog` só aparecem componentes avulsos.

Trecho onde eu adiciono os painéis :

```
    pnlPrincipal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Painel Principal
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pnlPrincipal);

    pnlFunc = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Painel dos dados do funcionário
    pnlFunc.setLayout(null);
    pnlFunc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (610, 150));
    pnlPrincipal.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, pnlFunc);

    pnlDep = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Painel do grid
    pnlDep.setLayout(null);
    pnlDep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (610, 300));
    pnlDep.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Dependentes"));
    pnlPrincipal.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, pnlDep);
```

Depois dessa parte do código, eu dou `new` a todos os componentes que vou usar no `pnlFunc`, e depois adiciono eles ao painel:

```
    pnlFunc.add(lblNome);
    pnlFunc.add(lblCpf);
    pnlFunc.add(lblEnd);
    pnlFunc.add(txtNome);
    pnlFunc.add(txtCpf);
    pnlFunc.add(txtEnd);
```

Depois desse trecho, eu dou `new` em todos os componentes que vou usar no `pnlDep`:

```
    btnAdd = new JButton("Adicionar");
    btnAdd.setBounds(25, 110, 100, 20);
    btnRemove = new JButton("Remover");
    btnRemove.setBounds(135, 110, 100, 20);
    pnlDep.add(btnAdd);
    pnlDep.add(btnRemove);

    scr = new JScrollPane();
    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Nome","Data de nascimento"},10);
    grid = new JTable(dtm);

    grid.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    grid.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    grid.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

    grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
    grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

    grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
    grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

    scr.setViewportView(grid);
    pnlDep.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scr);
```

Depois eu adiciono mais dois botões avulsos na janela, e eles são os únicos que aparecem na janela, o resto dos elementos não aparecem ...
OBS: O tamanho da janela é : 650x500 !

Comment: Em que momento você está adicionando o `pnlDep` no dialog? Além disso, `pnlDep.add(btnRemove);`, você deveria definir a posição no layout.

Comment: Na quarta linha :`getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pnlDep);`, mas o método `.setBounds();` do `btnRemove` não já faz isso pra mim ? '-'

Comment: Quem você adiciona primeiro: o Jpanel ou o scrollpane? Este último vai tomar todo o espaço para si, se não for definido um tamanho. Adicione como você está adicionando todos os componentes na dialog também, o problema pode ser a ordem.

Comment: @DiegoF Veja minha pergunta, alterei algumas coisas !

Comment: Quando o sentido disso? `pnlFunc = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
    pnlFunc.setLayout(null);`

Comment: Tente dar um `pack()` após adicionar todos os paineis no Frame/Dialog.